# How to list font styles for specified fonts

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, fonts

I'm working on app where I need costomized menu for picking and styling fonts.
I have already listed all available fonts, but I wasn't albe to list styles (like bold, italic, ...) for specified font. Is there a way to do so?
Is there a way how to find out list of styles (like bold, italic...) for specified font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a font style. There are just members of a font family. In OS X, NSFontManager will tell you the `availableMembersOfFontFamily:`. Note also `availableFontNamesWithTraits:`, which shows the correspondence between a trait and a font.

Comment: Thank you availableMembersOfFontFamily: was what I was looking for.